# Unable to fetch data by checking if one list is equal to other list in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I am trying to fetch records from the table `UserBookmark` where tag is equal to category.

My code is as follows:

views.py:

```
def home(request):

    category=Category.objects.values_list('category',flat = True).filter(user=request.user.pk)
    category = list(category)
    print category
    bookmarks = UserBookmark.objects.filter(tag__name__in = category)
    print bookmarks
    return render(request,'home.html',{'bookmarks':bookmarks})
```

models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    category= models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s'%(self.user,self.category)

class UserBookmark(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    bookmark = models.URLField()
    tag = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%i %s %s'%(self.id,self.user,self.bookmark)
```

But when I print bookmarks in `views.py` , I get an empty set.I tried printing category as well , it gives :

```
u"[u'Data Science', u'Python', u'Android', u'Data Analytics']"]
```

And when I try this in shell:

```
UserBookmark.objects.filter(tag__name__in = [u'Data Science', u'Python', u'Android', u'Data Analytics'])
```

I do get a resultset

```
<QuerySet [<UserBookmark: 24 user12 https://github.com/shreyag12?tab=stars>, <UserBookmark: 24 user12 https://github.com/swapnil?tab=stars>, <UserBookmark: 26 user13 https://github.com/retme7/My-Slides>, <UserBookmark: 26 user13 https://github.com/retme7/My-Slides>, <UserBookmark: 26 user13 https://github.com/retme7/My-Slides>, <UserBookmark: 27 user14 https://github.com/sunny2krGupta/Bigquery-series>, <UserBookmark: 28 user14 https://github.com/ctfs/write-ups-2017>]>
```

Can someone guide me in this?

Comment: I think you should try to achieve your goal without converting queryset to list, it will ease your life.

Comment: @DavidD. u mean i should remove this  category = list(category)?

Comment: @SwatiSingh can you check the type of category you got in the code? I think it's a unicode.

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal category is u"[u'Data Science', u'Python', u'Android', u'Data Analytics']"]

Comment: @SwatiSingh Could you please check the type of category using type(category) and post here what is the type they are showing?

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
this is what i get when i print type(category)

Comment: Can you check with this change in the code `bookmarks = UserBookmark.objects.filter(tag__name__in = [category])` adding category in list

Comment: When you're doing `list(category)`, you are nesting the list returned from `values_list`. And SQL is unable to match a list to a varchar.

Comment: @ShikharChauhan i have removed that category = list(category) but it is still not working

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal still not working

Comment: @ShikharChauhan Maybe that extra "u" in the category is causing the problem but i dont know how to remove it

Comment: @SwatiSingh What does `type(category)` return before you convert it into list?

Comment: @SwatiSingh Did you add the tag value to the database using **form.save_m2m()**?

Comment: @ShikharChauhan this is what i get when i do print type(category)  <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal no i am not using form, i have just done obj.save()

Comment: @SwatiSingh Ok, then is there any entry for field **tag** inside the model UserBookmars? Could you please check that too.

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal yes in my model UserBookmark tag = TaggableManager()

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by converting category which looked like this

```
 u"[u'Data Science', u'Python', u'Android', u'Data Analytics']"]
```

category2=ast.literal_eval(category[0])

category2 [u'Data Science', u'Python', u'Android', u'Data Analytics']and

then using bookmarks = UserBookmark.objects.filter(tag__name__in = category2)

It worked!

Comment: Happy to see that.

Comment: @VijeshVenugopal Thanku :)

Comment: it's my pleasure